# plot vertices in c++ graphically for graphs

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

is it possible to draw a adjacency graph like the one shown below in c++ 
and show it graphically.
is this even possible with C++

[image: Graph]

if yes can some one please point me to the correct library or tutorial.
or an example or would be really helpful.
i would be using visual studio 2015 for this task.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of plotting libraries google search will offer you, but they do require downloading source and building them which is sometimes not trivial especially for a beginner.

I suggest looking at [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) which as you can see has similar graphics to your example. Good walk through on how to build it could be found [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/graphviz-and-c/184402049) with specifics related to VS [here](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/winbuild.html).